# Calculating adjusted p-values from matrix while retaining matrix dimensions in R

Tags: r, matrix, p-value

I calculated between- and within-individual correlations using the `statsBy` function from the psych package as follows:

`statsBy(df[,c(1,10,12,13,14,17,20,24:25)], "group", na.rm = TRUE)`

I then extracted p-values via:

`print(stats$pwg, short=FALSE) #P-values within group cor`

This shows up as a matrix. However, as stated in the help of the `statsBy` function, these p-values are not corrected for multiple comparisons. I wish to do so via the bonferonni method.

I tried to do this by using the standard `p.adjust` command. However, this converts my matrix to a class (I think it's a class at least?) of numeric values. This causes 2 issues:

1. I have no idea which p-value belongs to which two variables.
2. I can't use the p-values as a matrix for the `corrplot` function (From the corrplot package).

Is there a way to use p.adjust while retaining the structure of the p-value matrix? Preferably with the original headers intact (though that isn't necessary per se).

Alternatively, is there another function in order to calculate bonferonni adjusted p-values without changing the matrix setup?

Comment: `M[] <- p.adjust(M)`?

Comment: Perfect, simple yet does exactly what I wanted. Thank you! Could you reply as answer, so I can accept it.